# Reports API Google - Calendar Audit Activity Events

Tags: java, google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-api-java-client, google-workspace

I'm trying to use this API(https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities/list) to list calendar activities for G Suite users but this error appears:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter applicationName must conform to the pattern (admin)|(docs)|(login)

My Code is:

```
Reports reports = new Reports.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credencial).build();

Activities activities = reports.activities()
                        .list("all", "calendar")
                        .setPageToken(nextPageToken)
                        .setMaxResults(10)
                        .execute();
```

When I use the login option it works for me

can anybody help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The reports API quickstart for java should help. [Reports API Java](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/quickstart/java). You have to ensure that the second param of .list("all",***) conforms to the version you are using. Example
.list("all","docs") would return the list of activities for the docs application from all users in your relative domain. Make sense?